# Testing ReactJS with PhantomJS - change SELECT value

Tags: jquery, reactjs, phantomjs

Im trying to test ReactJS with PhantomJS,

I cannot seem to trigger change SELECT event:

```
                selectWidth = [];
                selectPath =  $("#pdp-width-select").first()
                options = $("option", selectPath);
                options.each(function () {
                    $(this).attr("selected","selected");
                    $(this).trigger("change");
                    selectWidth.push({
                        text: $(this).text(),
                        value: $(this).val(),
                        stock: $("._1HQVd").text()
                    })
                })
```

This code tries to trigger the change event and fetch the stock value.

But it doesn't work.

I also tried this method:

[Change the selected value of a drop-down list with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499405/change-the-selected-value-of-a-drop-down-list-with-jquery)

[How to Change select value using PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40245699/how-to-change-select-value-using-phantomjs)

[How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

```
                selectWidth = [];
                selectPath =  $("#pdp-width-select").first()
                options = $("option", selectPath);
                options.each(function (i) {
                    selectPath[0].selectedIndex = i;
                    selectWidth.push({
                        text: $(this).text(),
                        value: $(this).val(),
                        stock: $("._1HQVd").text()
                    })
                })
```

NOTE: I cannot get it to work in the Chrome Dev-tool also.

Answer (score 0):

solution

```
                evtName = 'change';
                var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                event.initMouseEvent(evtName, true, true, window,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
```

`$("select#pdp-width-select").val('83720')[0].dispatchEvent(event);`